# Select elements which have color:lightGreen in CSS using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I select elements which have property `color:lightGreen` in CSS using jQuery and then change it to `#666`?

Example Html:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1_ctl17___ID_DetailsHyperLink" 
    class="CorporateHyperlink" 
     href="/EstimateSite/Estimate/Details.aspx?ID=234"
     style="color:LightGreen;">Details</a>
```

Comment: What type of elements are they? Can you post some HTML?

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni look at my answer just change $("p") to $("a") then it will apply to all anchor elements ...

Comment: The devil's in the details... literally in this case. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("color") == "rgb(144, 238, 144)") {
        $(this).css("color", "#666");
    }
});
```

Or if you prefer using `filter`:

```
$("a").filter(function() {return $(this).css('color') == 'rgb(144, 238, 144)';})
.css("color", "#666");
```

**BUT** if you had the opportunity to edit the markup, you're best off adding the light green colour to a class, then applying the class to those elements, then you can have another class for your new colour, then change them like so:

```
$(".lightGreen").removeClass("lightGreen").addClass("newColour");
```

Comment: What? I took the idea of replacing "lightGreen" to the RGB values, that was all. I'll +1 you for that how's that? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("color") == "rgb(144, 238, 144)") {
        $(this).css("color", "#666");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z8Q5K/2/

It's working fine...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).css("color") == "rgb(144, 238, 144)") { 
        $(this).css("color", "#666");
    }
});
```