# How can i use "z-index" as an css attribute selector?

Tags: jquery, css

I need an attribute selector to match the first div element with an z-index and a value of 0.
tTis is how i tried to get hands on the element,by using the css attribute selector syntax in jquery:

```
$("div[z-index='0']").first().doSomeJqueryStuff() ....
```

In my document there is an explicitly set z-index with a value of 0 on a div element, but the selector returns no result.
Thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: How to select all elements that have a specific CSS property applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-property-applied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) CSS Selector Library.

Answer (score 10):

You can apply attribute selector to inline style attribute (* means contains):

```
div[style*="z-index: 0"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Really helped.

Comment: Make this the most voted answer. Pure CSS is the way, JQuery is unnecessary overhead in this case. Thanks Suraj.

Comment: Nice. However, note that this only works if the `z-index: 0` is specified using a `style` attribute. If the `z-index` rule is part of a ruleset, the element won't be selected.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
$('div').each(function({ 
    if ($('div').css('z-index') === '0') { // or ... === 0
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible. You can not select elemets based on **css attribute** values that way.

You should apply a **class** or an **id** to an element with your CSS value and use that instead or **iterate over all elements and check for presence of css attribute** (rather costly operation).

Answer (score 1):

You can check them one by one untile you found the first with z-index = 0 :

```
$('div').each(function({ 
    // Check doc about .css() function
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`z-index` is a CSS property and 0 its value.

CSS selectors are made of **HTML** (and SVG, ...) id, class, elements, attributes, pseudo and their values (and Sizzle, the selector part of jQuery is made the same way).  These CSS selectors are for CSS rules where CSS declarations (`property: value`) are written and will style the HTML document.