# find element by css property

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` which contain about 100 other `div` elements. Each of `div` element have `top` and `left` properties. How can I find a `div` which have the largest `left` properties?
I need to best perfomance.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a way of getting out of checking all of them...

Comment: I think you have to loop through all divs

Comment: possible duplicate of `:)` [jQuery: How to select all elements that have a specific CSS property applied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-property-applied)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAYWD/)**

```
var divWithTopLeft = null;
var maxLeft = 0;
$('div').each(function(){
    left = this.style.left.replace('px','');
    if(left > maxLeft )
    {
         maxLeft = left;
         divWithTopLeft = this;
    }   
});
```

Comment: Jfyi, if you define `.class1 { position:relative; }` in the fiddle, then you can also use `this.offsetLeft` property instead of the `this.style.left.replace('px','');` to make the code run a lil bit faster.