# How to apply function to all elements having border-radius property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The idea is making some border-radius effect in IE 7/8, so I've decided to use [jquery.corner.js](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) library. To make it more generic I want to write some script which applies `corner()` function to all elements within a page having border-radius property.

For example, for this element

```
.someElement
{
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

function must do the following

```
   $(".someElement").corner("10px");
```

The problem is that **I want to apply rounded corners to all elements, including dynamically added elements and elements which are inheriting border-radius property among some action(hover, click, etc.).** Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1220873/1216394). You need a loop of all elements.

Comment: Sounds like it's going to be a lot of work since you're also generating HTML dynamically. IE8 usage is declining sharply; one of the rare occasions where time is on your side. Are you bound by requirements?

Comment: Yes, the client wants border-radius effect in the places where previously images were used. I want to find some generic solution to avoid writing javascript in all pages.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a function that applies you css on every change.
To detect css style changes, see here:

[Event detect when css property changed using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery)

Then you need call that function on style change and on dom tree change (every time you append something into the page)....

I would advise you use a specific class to apply border radius css. This way you can select the rounded elements via jQuery class selectors.

Comment: That approach does not seem to be supported cross browser and i believe the op is looking for a cross browser solution or he wouldn't be having this issue in the first place.

Comment: AFAIK he just wants to apply border radius in IE so detecting style changes is a real option. That's the way css3pie does it. The border-radius specific class is an obvious reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a generic css class that is used on all elements that have rounded borders and then use that class in your selector.

You will have to do this in a document ready handler. This will of course only apply rounded borders to elements that currently exists. If you want to cover elements loaded with ajax you can do the following:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings)
{
    $(xhr.responseText).find(".class-that-applies-rounded-borders").corner("10px");
});
```