# Insert element into page with javascript & shift page down accordingly.

Tags: javascript, css, position

I'm working on a chrome extension that needs to insert a position fixed iframe into the top of some webpages.  I have no control over the pages that will be modified.  At the moment I can insert the iframe but it covers up some of the page, but I want to be able to reserve space for it.  Problem is when I add a margin or padding to the body of the page, the other fixed elements on the page don't tally up with where they're meant to be.

How can I inject an element with javascript that I can be 100% sure that it will show at the top of the page and not hide anything under it, or mess up the positions anywhere else?

Comment: How about replacing the page by a frameset?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but some websites don't take too kindly to being in frames.

Comment: And as I don't have control over what sites this may appear on, it could be a problem

Comment: How about apply to body -webkit-transform: translateY(*your_block_height*px), then add your iframe to body as first child and apply -webkit-transform: translate(-*your_block_height*px)

Comment: Thanks anton_byrna, that worked and was the most simple method; I wasn't aware of that css property.  Do you want to add an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about apply to body `-webkit-transform: translateY(*your_block_height*px)`, then add your iframe to body as first child and apply `-webkit-transform: translate(-*your_block_height*px)`

Comment: That's what I did, thanks. Future readers please note that there's a bug in chromium where -webkit-transform stops fixed positions being 'fixed', but I'm going to use firefox instead.

Answer (score 0):

Cycle through the fixed elements and increase the "top" attribute by an amount equal to the height of the inserted element.

```
var myTop;

$('body div').each(function(){
   if($(this).css('position')=='fixed'){
      myTop = $(this).css('top');
      $(this).css('top',mytop + 100);
   };
});
```

I'm pretty sure you'll have to do some research and tweaking to get this working 100% though. For instance, the 'body div' selector will only move fixed divs down by 100 pixels. You can look here for more information:

- [Jquery .each() function](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [Selecting elements with a specific CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-property-applied)

Although just to warn you this could be a slow process on some pages. Someone else may have a better method.

Comment: Thanks, but I've decided to go with anton_byrna's css approach as it's probably faster in the browser.