# How do I get the current content to hide it?

Tags: jquery

I need to hide the content that is displayed in a div and replace it with other content when the user clicks a link. All of the content is inside of a div#content. Each content selection is then inside another div.

```
<div id = content>
    <div id = defaultTabs class = contentContainer>content</div>
    <div id = html5Tabs class = contentContainer>content</div>
    <div id = css3Tabs class = contentContainer>content</div>
    <div id = jqueryTabs class = contentContainer>content</div>
</div>
```

When the page first loads `defaultTabs` has css that sets `display:block`. The rest are hidden via css on `.contentContainer { display:none;}`. When a nav link is clicked the currently displayed content needs to be hidden and the new selection displayed.

I do not know how to get the currently displayed content, if someone could explain how to do that, I can do the rest of it.

Comment: why don't you use a jquery plugin like jquery ui or [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)?

Comment: Doesn't your `class`es and `id`s have quote marks around them?

Comment: Could you put up a jsfiddle example, or a link to your site?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to do what you are exactly requesting.

[Select all elements that have a specific CSS, using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-property-applied)

However to achieve the same effect, I just hide all the div's and then reveal the one that I want the user to see.

Comment: I think I may have a way of doing it. I should be able to get a list of divs by there class name. Use each() and the attr(id) to get the div id and set that to display:none.

Comment: Yes.  There are quite a few ways to select the divs and hide them.  Your question seemed to be asking just to select based on the css property.