# How to find a background and then set other background in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this for now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
   var allTdElements = $( "td > div" );
   //logic in here
   $(document).find(allTdElements).css("background-color", "blue" );                                        
});
```

I find all **td** has **div** in it but now I want to find in that **div** what background has. For example It could be 2 different colors **green** and **red**. And if its red i'll change the color to another, and green the same as red.

But between the instruction of  `var allTdElements = $( "td > div" );` and  `$(document).find(allTdElemen...` i don't know how to search it.

After change a few thing I got this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    var allTdElements = $( "td > div" );
    var color = $( allTdElements ).css( "background-color" );

    if (color == 'red')
       $(document).find(allTdElements).css("background-color", "red" );
    else
       $(document).find(allTdElements).css("background-color", "green" );                               
});
```

But I want to change the td what contain the div.

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

Thanks to @Stewartside. I'll write the solution of anyone has the same problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('td div').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
    });
 });
```

Comment: Try with `....css('backgroundColor', 'blue')`

Comment: I updated my answer with more information.

Comment: I updated the post with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery will usually get the background-color out in RGB format, so therefore you are going to have do a check against the RGB version of the colour you are searching for.

I have also used `.each()` which should make things clearer and easier to understand.

Below is a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td div').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
  });

});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
td:nth-child(1) div {
  background: red;
}
td:last-child div {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Test 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Test 2</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>Test 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But the problem I have is some div's has red background and some green. So I want to pass the propierty background div to td because the div cannot fill the whole content of td.

Comment: there is a background-color in the div, but i want to set the same blackground the div has to td. That's why i'm trying to get the value of div to pass it to the td.

Comment: Thanks, english is is not my native lenguage and its quite difficult to explant what I want.

Comment: yes! That worked very well. I updated the first post with the new solution you provided. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

the following code will change blue to green and vise versa

```
$('td > div').each(function(){
var color=$(this).css('background-color');
if(color=='blue')
$(this).css('background-color','green');
else
$(this).css('background-color','blue');  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, what worked out. But how I do to change the css to the td who contain the div?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a selector. What you could do is find out which classes are responsible for the background colors, and make a selector for those, e.g. `$('td > div.red-background')`.

[A similar question has been asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-using-jquery)