# Find all display:none attributes and add in aria-hidden attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, wai-aria

Is there a way to search for all the instances where property `display:none` is used and add the attribute `aria-hidden="true"` using JavaScript.

My site has hundreds of instances of this and i am looking for a quicker way.

Could it be something like this: (added to a function)

```
$(*).css( "display", "none" ).attr( "aria-hidden", "true" );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220834/select-all-elements-that-have-a-specific-css-using-jquery

Comment: `$('*').filter(function(){ return $(this).css('display').toLowerCase().indexOf('none') > -1 }).attr("aria-hidden", "true");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use **[hidden()](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)** selector to identify all display none element

```
$( ":hidden").attr( "aria-hidden", "true" );
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cvku3fno/5/)**

Answer (score 9):

The effect of `aria-hidden="true"` is to instruct the browser to not expose the element to the accessibility tree even if it is not hidden.

The browsers do not expose any elements to the accessibility API that are `display:none`.

So what you are trying to do is totally redundant. It will have absolutely zero additional affect on accessibility. Save yourself the effort and do something more productive.

Comment: Screen reader still reads out content that has the display:none attribute so the aria-hidden is in fact required

Comment: @RAS that is absolute poppycock

Comment: @RAS here is a reference to one of the specs that talks about when content should not be exposed to the accessibility tree http://www.w3.org/TR/core-aam-1.1/#h-exclude_elements2

Comment: @Tin Both `display: none` and `visibility: hidden` aren't exposed by SR. Other declarations may or may not depending on SR (`opacity:0`, etc) but those 2 ones are perfectly safe to use

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

You can use filter, but it is not optimal solution:

```
$("*").filter(function() { return $(this).css("display") == "none" })
```

Comment: He's looking to add the ARIA, not detect it.