# how to select element based one style attribute in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `<h2>` with this style:

```
<h2 style="color='#ccc'; font-size='12px'; margin='10px';"></h2>
```

How can I select that just with 1 property ? like this: `$("h2[style=color='#ccc']");`

I can do that with all property, like this:

```
$("h2[style='color=#ccc; font-size=12px; margin=10px;']");
```

But I want to select via **just one property** (color), is it possible ?

Comment: I believe the jquery function is [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [attribute-contains-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$("h2[style*='color=#ccc']")
```

---

Please note that `color: '#ccc'` is *not* a valid CSS; the color code must not be quoted.

Also note that this solution uses a single selector, but it does not handle non-inline CSS, nor the whitespace inside inline CSS.

If you want to handle CSS properly, you have to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/Filter/) — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14313490/2170192) for an example. Note that it may have some performance impact.

Also, please consider using classes for JS logic.