# How to select last flexbox element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a grid-system which can be 3 to 1 column wide. The boxes are always 320x320 sized. Each box has a class-name which determine its position in the grid, eg. 
`<div class="sp3-om sp2-4r sp1-6"></div>`.
One column is pure flexbox, eg. "sp1-6" has `order: 6`.
To append an back-button i need to select the last box, which is :visible and has the highest order. I have tried multiple things like

```
$('.box').filter(function(){ return $(this).css('order') == 6 })
```

How can i select the last visible flexbox element, because .last() selects the last element in DOM, not the last one visible on the screen.

Comment: Show your HTML please

Comment: here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/200c5px3/1/ - the goal is a grid where you can set the postion of each box in the grid via classname depending on the column-count.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1220834/3597276

Comment: that post i got my first line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

$('.grid').find('.box:visible').eq($('.box:visible').length-1)

Hope this helps.

Comment: this seems interessting, but in this fiddle and on the live-system it selects the second last element http://jsfiddle.net/200c5px3/3/

Comment: using this with the live system it selects the last element in DOM, not the last flexbox-element...